# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWeb/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to execute a program in Spring MVC and below is the code. When i try to run the program, i see the error `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWeb/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb' ?:`and 404 error page appears, how can i fix this?.. The actual program code is at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm

**Web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Form Handling</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
           org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**HelloWeb-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.SpringMVC" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

**StudentController.java**

```
package com.SpringMVC;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
public class StudentController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView student() {
      return new ModelAndView("student", "command", new Student());
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Student student, 
   ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
      model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
      model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());

      return "result";
   }
}
```

**Student.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Student Information</h2>
<form:form method="POST" action="/HelloWeb/addStudent">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request path is incorrect. Try following;)

Remove `/HelloWeb` from `<form:form method="POST" action="/HelloWeb/addStudent">` like `<form:form method="POST" action="/addStudent">`

Or

Add `/HelloWeb` in your controller code like

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/HelloWeb")
public class StudentController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView student() {
      return new ModelAndView("student", "command", new Student());
   }
   @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Student student, 
   ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
      model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
      model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());

      return "result";
   }
```

Comment: made the above code change, but it still throws the same error in the console.

Comment: Both of that two ways?

Comment: yes, both of the two ways.

Comment: You just pick one of them to fix the exception. If you've just pick one of them, would you like provide more exception information for me please?